# Why all columns in Aggregate Report shows identical same values?

Tags: jmeter

Configured a Test Plan where I have checked the option 'Generate parent sample' in Transaction Controller, in order to get the stats of individual transactions. And ran the test on Non-GUI mode, but I get identical same values in all columns of Aggregate Report, such as; Average, Median, 90% Line, Min, Max, etc.

Is it because of the configuration I did in Transaction Controller or any other settings need to be configured in the jmeter.properties file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is absolutely expected assuming that your Transaction Controller ran once hence only one result is recorded. You will see the same output for any other singe sampler.

If you add more iterations on Thread Group level or via [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) you should see differences.

Check out [Using JMeter's Transaction Controller](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) guide to learn more about Transaction Controller use cases.